# I'm trying a simple routing method using flutter_bloc but this happened to me

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Message: Could not find the correct Provider above this Home Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.

Here's the blocProvider and blocBuilder set up you can get the jest of it I'm sure.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: BlocProvider<PageRoutingCubit>(
          create: (context) => PageRoutingCubit(),
        child: BlocBuilder<PageRoutingCubit, PageRoutingStates>(
            builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is PageRoutingProfileState) {
            return ProfileScreen();
          } else if (state is PageRoutingSettingsState) {
            return SettingsScreen();
          } else if (state is PageRoutingCartState) {
            return CartScreen();
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Error'),
            );
          }
        })),
```

I then added a drawer with button to control the body of the scaffold with said buttons.

````
```Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          DrawerButton(
                              onTap: () => context
                                  .read<PageRoutingCubit>()
                                  .BuildProfileScreen(),
                              text: 'Profile',
                              icon: Icon(Icons.person)),
                          DrawerButton(
                              onTap: () => context
                                  .read<PageRoutingCubit>()
                                  .BuildSettingsScreen(),
                              text: 'Settings',
                              icon: Icon(Icons.settings)),
                          DrawerButton(
                              onTap: () => context
                                  .read<PageRoutingCubit>()
                                  .BuildCartScreen(),
                              text: 'Cart',
                              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)),
                        ],
                      ),```
````

It keeps telling me to add a builder but I already supplied it with the builder it wants.
Please help me quickly and thank you.

Comment: Where does the context come from?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Scaffold with a `BlocProvider` **AND** wrap the Drawer with a regular  `Builder` widget so that you use the  context with the bloc added to it. If you don't want the "hack" with a Builder wrapping the Drawer, you could extract the drawer widget to its own widget and you will be able to access the bloc inside the passed down context.